# Extracting "filename" from full path in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

Does AS3 have a built in class / function to extract "filename" from a complete path. e.g. I wish to extract "**filename.doc**" from full path "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\filename.doc"

Answer (score 9):

For Air, you can try using [File](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filesystem/File.html) Class to extract file name

```
var file:File=new File("path_string");   
//path_string example "C:\\Windows\\myfile.txt"  
var filename:String = file.name;
```

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't you just do something basic like:

```
string filename = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1)
```

I know it's not a single function call, but it should work just the same.

Edited based on @Bryan Grezeszak's comment.

Comment: The fullpath string is dynamically picked up when user selects a file and looks like "c:\temp\abc.doc" 

lastIndexOf("\\") dosen't work for above.

Comment: why not? lastIndexOf("\\") means find the last '\' and tell me its index in the string..

Comment: You're on the right path, but you need to add one to the index to remove the actual slash from the final result :)

Answer (score 4):

First you want to find the last occurrence of / or \ in the path, do that using this:

```
var fSlash: int = fullPath.lastIndexOf("/");
var bSlash: int = fullPath.lastIndexOf("\\"); // reason for the double slash is just to escape the slash so it doesn't escape the quote!!!
var slashIndex: int = fSlash > bSlash ? fSlash : bSlash;
```

That will give you the index in the string that is right BEFORE that last slash. So then to return the portion of the string after that, you add one to the index (moving it past the last slash) and return the remainder of the string

```
var docName: String = fullPath.substr(slashIndex + 1);
```

To do this as a simple to use function, do this:

```
function getFileName(fullPath: String) : String
{
    var fSlash: int = fullPath.lastIndexOf("/");
    var bSlash: int = fullPath.lastIndexOf("\\"); // reason for the double slash is just to escape the slash so it doesn't escape the quote!!!
    var slashIndex: int = fSlash > bSlash ? fSlash : bSlash;
    return fullPath.substr(slashIndex + 1);
}

var fName: String = getFileName(myFullPath);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. However I have a dynamic path string which looks like "D:\temp\abc.doc". getFileName("D:\temp\abc.doc")returns "D:empabc.doc".

Comment: No you don't :) Backslashes act as escapes when you make a string, that's why \n makes a new line, \t makes a tab, etc. Your string of 'D:\temp\abc.doc' actually ends up as 'D:{tab}emp{symbol}bc.doc, you didn't actually make a string that contains any slashes unless you escape the slashes, like \\

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can use the [File](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class, or more specifically, the [File.separator](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filesystem/File.html#separator) static member if you're working with AIR. It should return "/" or "\", which you can plug in to @cmptrgeekken's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var file_ :File = new File("C:/Usea_/Dtop/sinim (1).jpg"); // or url variable ... whatever//

file_ = file_.parent;

trace(file_.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to do the job :

```
var tmpArray:Array<String>;
var fileName:String;

tmpArray = fullFilePath.split("\");
fileName = tmpArray.pop();
```

You have to take care if you are using Unix file system ("/") or Windows file system ("\").