# Remove full path with actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I actually remove the full path as in `C:\program files\app\filename.jpg` so that the only left is `filename.jpg`?

Substr or Substring can be use in this case to remove after detecting the first occurrence `\` or `/` by looping from the string end position.

Is there a better method?

Comment: This has been discussed before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743739/extracting-filename-from-full-path-in-actionscript-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`File`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class gives you a `name` property, that should give you what you want. For example:

```
var f:File = new File("C:\program files\app\filename.jpg");
trace("File name is: " + f.name);
```

The `File` class is AIR only. If you are working in the Flash Player, try the [`FileReference`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) class, which has the same property.

The implementation of this is platform agnostic so it should work correctly on both Mac and PC.

Comment: This is great and much better!